# PyTorch roll along batch of image

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I have a batch of image tensors with BxCxHxW and a shift tensor with Bx2 format, where B is the batch size.

As I know, `torch.roll(input, shifts, dims=None)` expect `shifts` parameters as int or tuples.
So if I want to use that function to roll all of my batch images, here is my current implementation:

```
for i in range(batch_size):
    images[i] = images[i].roll(shifts[i].tolist(), (1, 2))
```

I know this is inefficient, so I am wondering if there is any alternative for using the roll function with the shifts parameter as a batch. So, I can implement something like:

`images = images.roll(shifts, (2, 3))`.

Thank you.